# run a shell script using a variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables

[image: Write a bash shell script named Greeting, which prints the following message on the termianl when user type exit on the terminal]

I wrote the Greeting.sh script and I don't understand how to execute the script on exit command, I tried assigning it to the variable and then change access permission of that variable, but it  doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

time=`date|cut -f5 -d " "`
hrs=`echo $time|cut -f1 -d ":"`
min=`echo $time|cut -f2 -d ":"`

time1=`who|cut -f13 -d " "`
hrs1=`echo $time1|cut -f1 -d ":"`
min1=`echo $time1|cut -f2 -d ":"`

h=`expr $hrs - $hrs1`
m=`expr $min - $min1`

for ((i=0;i<50;i++))
do
        echo -ne "*"
done
echo ""

echo "Welcome to SLIIT $HOSTNAME Server!"
echo "You have spent $h hours and $m minutes with us."
echo "Goobye..! $LOGNAME"


for ((i=0;i<50;i++))
do
        echo -ne "*"
done
echo ""
```

I tried assigning like this

```
[ishIlan@localhost ~]$ chmod 777 Greeting.sh
[ishIlan@localhost ~]$ exit=`Greeting.sh`
[ishIlan@localhost ~]$ chmod 777 $exit
[ishIlan@localhost ~]$ $exit
```

What should I do to make the program run when "exit" is typed on the terminal, please help me.

Comment: `alias exit="./Greeting.sh"`

Comment: @PS That won't actually exit the shell; it will run the script *intead* of exiting the shell.

Comment: True,  just answered Ops query.  Left op to figure that out.